# How to use Vaadin text Change Listener

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Good day.  I am working in a Vaadin project that has an html layout.  I would like to change the legend text on click.  Here is the html layout.

```
<vaadin-panel _id="namePanel" class="layoutContainer">
 <vaadin-vertical-layout>
    <vaadin-label style-name="colored" class="cssStyle"  _id="namePanel">
      <legend>Name</legend> 
    </vaadin-label>
```

Currently there is a ClickListener on this name Label that makes the fullName  visible after click
name.addContextClickListener(event -> showData());

```
  private void showData() {
    x++;
    boolean checking = false;
    if (x % 2 != 0) {
        checking = true;
    }
    fullName.setVisible(checking);
```

I need to Change the text(Label) "Name" to "Full Name" onClick.

So I figured out how to import JavaScript and how to throw an alert.

```
 Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("alert('Hello')");
```

I'm guessing I would go this route to change the text on click?

Or can I use a textListener with HTML contents?

Also how to I make Vaadin click respond to left click instead of right click?

Thanks for any advice you can give.

Comment: The context click listener is in effect a mouse right click listener, you want to a use click listener which is invoked on a left click.

Comment: why is the second `_id` the same as the first one?  can't you just change the value of that label?

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1 - Change Your Object

One option is to make the `Label` a Vaadin `Button` and style it so it does not look like a button, and then add a click listener.

### Option 2 - LayoutClickListener

Another option is to define and add a `LayoutClickListener` to the layout that contains the `Label`. Here's an example:

```
final Label fullName = new Label( "Name" );

VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

layout.addComponent( fullName );
layout.addLayoutClickListener( new LayoutClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void layoutClick( LayoutClickEvent event )
    {
        // whatever you want to do, the following may or may not be right
        if ( event.getClickedComponent() == fullName )
            ( (Label) event.getClickedComponent() ).setValue( "Full Name" );
    }
} );
```

For more info, take a look [at this Vaadin forum post](https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/184075)